# Nested async functions variable scope

Tags: node.js, async-await, puppeteer

I have this structure of code (including sockets and puppeteer):

```
client.on('find', (url) => {
    console.log(url);                         // url == "google.ru"
    (async function(){
        await page.goto(url);                 // url == "google.ru"
        await page.evaluate(async () => {
            var response = await fetch(url);  // url == undefined
            var json = await response.json();
            return json;
        });
    })();
});
```

I have tried some variations (closures etc.) but can't make it work. How to correctly pass **url** variable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`.evaluate` callback function runs in the page context, not in your main script context, that's why `url` is undefined.

Inside the callback you can access any `variable` defined in the browser global scope.

If you want to access `url` from inside `.evaluate` you can pass it as an argument.

```
page.evaluate(async (url) => {
    // browser context
    var response = await fetch(url);  
    var json = await response.json();
    return json;
}, url); // pass it as an argument
```